# Why is git asking me for a password?

Tags: windows, git, putty, tortoisegit

I'm using Windows XP, TortoiseGit (latest version) and Cygwin.  I have git.exe installed and on my path.  In TortoiseGit, I can execute pushes against the remote repository without being prompted for a password.  I assumed this was because I have defined this in my .git/config file ...

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://git@myrepo/myproject.git
    puttykeyfile = U:\\.ssh\\mykey.ppk
```

However, in Cygwin, when at the root directory of my project (the one where the .git folder is a child), I get prompted for a password ...

```
$ git push origin qa_release
git@myrepo's password:
```

Why am I prompted for a password when trying to push from Cygwin but not from TortoiseGit and how can I get Cygwin to behave like TortoiseGit (i.e. not ask me for a password)?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puttykeyfile` is a windows git thing, so you need to have your SSH set up for cygwin too. Git will use your regular SSH settings.

Is the .ppk file a regular SSH public key? If so, add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file, so cygwin git knows where to find it.

```
 Host myrepo
     IdentityFile /cygdrive/u/.ssh/mykey.ppk
```

You can test this quickly with a `ssh myrepo` in cygwin.

Comment: A variation of this worked for me.  Under "Host," I also added "User myuser" and "Hostname myhost" lines in addition to changing the identity file from the .ppk to the private key file.  Thanks, -

Comment: Btw, ppk IS NOT SSH public key. It's a putty`s private key.